# Cant create the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv

the following commands runs smmooth:

> csvfile <- file.path("C:/Users/Jbhanda/Desktop/deseq.csv")
> coldata <- read.csv(csvfile, row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> coldata

then I run another command just after that:

> coldata <- coldata[1:2,]
> coldata$names <- coldata$Run
> coldata$files <- file.path(dir, "quants", coldata$names, "quant.sf.gz")

It gives the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, files, value = character(0)) :
> replacement has 0 rows, data has 2

I want to know what is wrong in the data frame and how can i rectify the command

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: `file.path(dir, "quants", coldata$names, "quant.sf.gz")` probably produces zero results. Run that code independently in the console and see the result. For better help please provide reproducible a example.